# SSH tunneling on steroids

Tags: networking

I have a remote redis machine with no ssh and no open ports except to the same lan + a remote machine (on the same lan) with ssh + my pc outside the lan. What I'm trying to do (mostly to see if it's possible) is `redis-cli on my pc -> ssh tunnel to the ssh machine -> something -> redis` so it would work.
Is netcat + mkfifo the right way?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the following:

- YOUR_PC, has Redis client, SSH client, SSH access to SSH_SERVER
- SSH_SERVER, has SSH server, redis access to REDIS_SERVER
- REDIS_SERVER, has Redis server

Set up the tunnel from YOUR_PC, port 1234, to REDIS_SERVER:REDIS_PORT, via SSH_SERVER

```
ssh SSH_SERVER -L 1234:REDIS_SERVER:REDIS_PORT
```

On another terminal, on YOUR_PC, run the redis client (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678950):

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

We have redis connected through stunnel. That way you don't have to always establish the ssh connection, which can be a problem. Here is an article on how to setup redis through stunnel, which I won't copy into this answer. Feel free to edit.

http://bencane.com/2014/02/18/sending-redis-traffic-through-an-ssl-tunnel-with-stunnel/

Answer (score 1):

This works, I wonder if there is a better solution.
SSH tunnel + nc proxy

`ssh $ssh_server -L $port:localhost:$port "mkfifo /tmp/backpipe; nc -k -l localhost $port 0</tmp/backpipe | nc $redis_server $port | 1>/tmp/backpipe"`